# Why is my code for prefix to infix not displaying an output

Tags: c++

I am writing this code on Visual studio 2019 which converts a prefix number to infix.
When i press F5 the window says: (process 10428) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.

I don't know much about C++. I know Java and python fairly well but our instructor wants us to use C++.

```
string s[7];
int f = -1;

void push(string a)
{

    s[f++] = a;


}

string pop()
{

    return s[f--];

}

bool isop(char x) {

    switch (x)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    case '*':
    case '/':
        return true;

    }
    return false;
}





int main() {

    string a = "*+ab+cd";
    reverse(a.begin(), a.end());


    for (int i = 0;i<int(a.length());i++) {



        if (isop(a[i])) {

            string v1 = pop();
            string v2 = pop();
            string h = "(" + v1 + a[i] + v2 + ")";

            push(h);



        }
        else {
            push(string(1, a[i]));

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0;i < 7;i++)
    {
        cout << s[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The shown code exhibits many unsafe and dangerous programming practices that often result in this kind of a crash. Therefore, the best thing to do is use your debugger to run your code one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables, on each step, and observe its logical execution. This is exactly what a debugger is for. Have you used your debugger to debug this program already, and if not why not? Knowing and being able to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: You are initializing f to -1 and then using that as an index into your s array. That is invalid, because you are attempting access memory outside the bounds of the array. Change the initialization of f to 0 instead of -1. That’s for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here (it would be exactly the same in Java)

```
string s[7];
int f = -1;

void push(string a)
{
    s[f++] = a;
}
```

The first time you push `f` is `-1` so you have an out of bounds array access. I guess you meant this

```
void push(string a)
{
    s[++f] = a;
}
```

You could have avoided this error by using a `std::vector` (similar to an ArrayList in Java).